# Responseive containers with different width in smartphone & PC - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I make responseive conatiner in bootstrap that in smartphone will be be full width and in pc will be 70% width?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code in the question.

Comment: I'm sure that can be done using the features of [Boostrap 4 Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Hope it helps you. An idea could be using classes **col-12 offset-md-2 col-md-8** on the same container, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using **CSS's media queries** ([read more](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)). I have created a class which you can use.

```
.container-custom {
  width: 100%;
} 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container-custom {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```